# Is there a way to access Google Maps Placelists via an API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Placelists are the user generated lists of places that a user can create by starring a location and adding it to a list

Comment: Did you find any solution? They are neither available in the takeouts (takeout.google.com).

Answer (score -1):

Google is providing place library for Place List for map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: I don't see a mention of Placelists on that link.

Comment: Here is example But it is deprecated now :( ,https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search